# Work around for Canvas crashing in Google Chrome 29

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

Does anyone know a work around to prevent HTML5 canvas from crashing in Google Chrome 29.

After so many redraws canvas crashes consistently on Windows Chrome 29 (not 28 or 30). An easy way to reproduce:
1. Get on a Microsoft Windows machine (this problem will not occur on Linux/MAC OS X)
2. Goto: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-drag-and-drop-stress-test-with-1000-shapes/
3. Click refresh

I posted this issue to Google's Chromium bug tracker:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=280153

But I'm looking if anyone has found or can think of a work around for this problem.

Comment: No crash for me Chrome 29 nor Canary 31 (Windows).

Comment: It looks like 29.0.1547.62 m is now making this test past, I have others that are still failing -- I'll have to simplify and post those

Comment: This issue is coming back in my Chrome.. v40.0.2214.111 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to make it crash with Chrome 29 nor Canary 31 (Windows).

But as to work around:

Try to segment the load on the browser by splitting tasks that are heavy and time consuming into parts. Each part can be called with `setTimeout`.

This will give the browser some time to "breath" and execute other events in the event queue which makes the browser happy.

```
function heavyTask(callback) {

     var dataForTask;

     function segment1() {
         /* execute one part of heavy task - do something with dataForTask */

         setTimeout(segment2, 11);
     }

     function segment2() {
         /* execute one part of heavy task - do something with dataForTask */

         setTimeout(segment3, 11);
     }

     function segmentN() {
         /* execute one part of heavy task - do something with dataForTask */

         /// DONE!
         callback();
     }
}
```

In theory you could use a value of `0` for delay with `setTimeout` however this does not always work (browser dependent). A value of 11 comes close to the minimum event loop time so this should work with most browsers.